# How can i compare date without time part in linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I compare date without Time part in Nullable DateTime? In my model I have datetime field as

```
public DateTime? AdjustmentDate { get; set; }
```

I tried to compare dates as

```
if (!request.reconciliationDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
    filterResult = filterResult.Where(rd => 
        rd.AdjustmentDate <= request.reconciliationDate.Date).ToList();
```

and `reconciliationDate` declared as

```
public DateTime reconciliationDate { get; set; }
```

but when I search using reconciliationDate I get the date as `{5/20/2020 12:00:00 AM}` I enter date as `5/20/2020`. I am trying to compare with date `5/20/2020` but doesn't find it,

How can I take the time part out from nullable DateTime?

I tried DbFunctions.TruncateTime(request.reconciliationDate.Date) but i get `DbFunctions doesnt contain definition TruncateTime`

Comment: "12:00:00 AM" *is* 00:00:00, are you comparing against string?

Comment: @Martheen I just want to compare dateTime field with DateTime  value entered, i updated the question

Comment: Use the `.Date` property

Comment: @RufusL Its wired I tried that as well but no luck

Comment: Put the breakpoint and see the actual values during the comparison

Comment: `!request.reconciliationDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue)` will validate to `true` if AdjustmentDate is 'null'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Nullable<T>` object stores the value of `T` in the `.Value` property, and has a handy `.HasValue` property to let you know if it's not null. So if you're comparing a `DateTime?` with a `DateTime`, you can do something like:

```
if (!request.reconciliationDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
    filterResult = filterResult
        .Where(rd =>
            rd.AdjustmentDate.HasValue &&
            rd.AdjustmentDate.Value.Date <= request.reconciliationDate.Date)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If(dt1.Date == dt2.Date)
Will this not work?

Comment: Divya if you see my question that's how i tried it that didn't work for me.